# display images on mouseover for each slice

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to display images on mouseover for each slice. How can I load an image from a JSON array in this script? [image]

I'd like the tooltip to display an image loaded from an external file.

```
var data = [
{
    "str_lab": „A“,
    "num": 300,
„image: “http://graphics/a.svg"
},
{
    "str_lab": „B“,
    "num": 44,
„image: “http://graphics/b.svg"

},
{
    "str_lab": „C“,
    "num": 215,
„image: “http://graphics/c.svg"
},
{
    "str_lab": „D“,
    "num": 30,
„image: “http://graphics/d.svg"
} ];
```

Link to code: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sSITuaI2ErWJjdlDbQIQ?p=preview)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? Or supply us with some sample images you'd like to display?

Comment: I still have the problem. Can you see my pictures what I would like to insert. I think 
„image: “graphics/a.svg" (4 different pictures )  from my files or 
or 4 Images on another Server example: (href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Bananas.jpg")

Comment: @RobertAndersson i hope you understand what i mean it. Should I insert the pictures with link on my server.  How can I do mouseover for each slice on the center circle with pictures from the server (href).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Code Plunkr with mouseover resolving images (with href) as a pattern](https://plnkr.co/edit/PBQRcHYw88y9RQGeGoj8?p=preview)

**Source** for the sample images: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery

Snapshot of your data:

```
{
    "str_lab": "A",
    "num": 100,
    "image": 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png'
},
```

I had to rearrange a lot of `svg` elements ( especially the `defs` and the center `circle`). Do remember that it's always recommended to append `defs` with filters and patterns to the `SVG` and not the `<g>` element within it **AND** if you do, make sure the corresponding elements are `transform`ed accordingly.

**Here are some relevant changes in your code:**

```
var pattern = defs.append('pattern')
 .attr('id', 'image')
 .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
 .attr('width', 300)
 .attr('height', 300);

var image = pattern.append('image').attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0).attr('width', 124)
.attr('height', 124);
```

**Center circle on mouseover calls the pattern image set by `d.data.image`:**

```
    d3.select('pattern image')
        .attr('xlink:href', d.data.image);
    svg.select('circle.image')
        .attr('fill','url(#image)')
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: thank you. I would like to mouse out to remove image. 

d3.select('pattern image').remove(); 

But the image will not show the image again if hover over this diagram.



[link](http://embed.plnkr.co/2qI66WCvSPewuHeiXJCj/)

Comment: If you remove the image the first time mouse is out, it won't be found the next time mouse is over an arc. You'll have to append the image every time. Instead change it to null, here's a fork: [Mouseout fix](https://plnkr.co/edit/VssQGF9VFe5yKqhCWcQv?p=preview)